# Исчезли файлы с сервера на Debian 8 под управлением VMware ESXi 5.5, как починить?

Tags: debian, файловая-система, vmware

Имеется VMware ESXi 5.5, под ним запущен Debian 8 сервер который работал несколько лет без особых проблем.

При попытке добавить существующий диск с разделами и данными, отключенный от другого сервера на Debian 7 (диск разбит и отформатирован в нем под ext3), после перезапуска сервера, пропало часть каталогов с файлами сайтов. Некоторые файлы якобы существуют но при попытке их открыть по ssh, выдается ошибка что мол они не существуют.
После отключения второго диска, и перезагрузки, часть файлов вернулось на место и почти все сайты заработали за исключением одного, в нем так же отсутствует каталог с файлами.
Можно как то попытаться отремонтировать файловую систему?

> Диск подключался без остановки виртуальной машины.

Comment: файловая система в linux ремонитруется стандартно fsck -f. Не забудьте отмонтировать ремонтируемый кусок.

Comment: @Smithson отмонтировал принудительно весь диск, и выполняю команду fsck -fy /dev/sda1 пишет ошибку что не может найти такого диска и мол он не примонтирован...

Comment: Так может он /dev/sda1[abcd] ? Нужно не диск, а именно раздел проверять.